# Function Modification

Tags: c

I had a question regarding the following function:

[image]

I am wondering how to alter the function so that it displays elements in descending order (5,4,3,2,1 e.g.). Is it simply a matter of switching the signs within the conditionals?

Comment: Please don't post images. Post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the previous post you should only change the sign.
I have included the solved problem with an example and explanations:

```
//the right side vector is still unsorted
//the left side of the vector is still sorted
void selection_sort(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, smallest=0, temp;
    if (n==1)
        return;
    //find the smallest number from the right of current position
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        if (a[i]<a[smallest])
            smallest=i;
    //if the last element is NOT the smallest swap
    if(smallest<n-1)
    {
        temp=a[n-1];
        a[n-1]=a[smallest];
        a[smallest]=temp;
    }
    //call recursively
    selection_sort(a,n-1);
}

int main() {

    int vec[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    selection_sort(vec,5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d ",vec[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

*Please note* that this approach is not as **efficient** as looping inside the code inside of a `for` loop.
The efficient approach pseudo code is:

```
for each element from vector (you can pass the last one)
   find the largest element to the right
      swap current element with the largest
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Instead of searching for the largest value and swapping, you search for the smallest value and swap that instead.

Just write out the function and give it a try.